# NaN for p-values using logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, p-value, hessian

I cannot perform logistic regression properly.
I had errors like "Singular matrix", problems with Hessian, though my dataset is not correlated.

None of those 3 codes run smoothly:

>

```
 model = sm.Logit(y1,X1.astype(float))

> 1. #result = model.fit(method='bfgs')
> #result.summary() 

> 2. #result = model.fit(method='powell') result.summary()

> 3. #result=model.fit_regularized
>    #result.params
```

*ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).*

With powell method or bfgs method I got 'non' for p-values.

```
#define the response (y) and predictors (X)
X1 = df1.loc[:, df.columns != 'OPENED']
y1 = df1['OPENED']
model = sm.Logit(y1,X1.astype(float))
result = model.fit(method='powell')
result.summary()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykIIg.png)

Any ideas?

What to check? What to use? Thanks.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as all relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: cant see the way how to upload the data, sorry...but the post is updated

Comment: Good news, I found the mistake, but still some of the p-values are NaN...dont know why...